# Finding solution of overdetermined system that is within a prime finite field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, matrix-decomposition

### Setup

I have an applied math problem with a system,
\begin{align*}
 Y = XA
\end{align*}
Where $Y\in\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^{100\times 1}, X\in\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^{100\times800}$ and $A\in \mathbb{Q}^{800}$. Although I would like to find an $A$ in the finite field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Where $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is the finite field of $\{0,1\}$ which means the matricies $Y,X$ only contain the elements $\{-1,0,1\}$.

### Question

How do I find an $A$ of this over-determined system with either integer, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients?

### Current Solution

To solve this system I am using rank-revealing QR factorization to find a solution,
\begin{align*}
   XP &= QR\\
X_{reduced} &= XP_1
\end{align*}
Where $P_1\in\{0,1\}^{100\times 100}$ is a permutation matrix that puts the 100 columns associated with the orthogonal basis of $X$ to make the resulting matrix $X_{reduced}\in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^{100\times 100}$ square and full rank resulting in a solution $A$ that has rational coefficients.

### Problem

If I just brute force tried to search for all permutations of columns in $X$ there are $10^{287}$ permutations. I need a closed form or reduced search method for finding a combination of columns that results in ideally some prime integer coefficient solution matrix $A$.

Comment: How do ou define $XA$ when the field of $X$ is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and the field of $A$ is $\mathbb Q?$ Also, $-1=1$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Yeah, I was not sure if I was allowed to say that -1 was in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ sorry. I don't know how to describe a finite field including negative integers $\{-1,0,1\}$. Could you tell me how I would use notation for that?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $A$ is currently within $\mathbb{Q}$ the whole point is to get $A$ into the same field. Or I suppose because I am using the wrong notation. My goal is to have $Y,X,A\in \{-1,0,1\}^{\cdot \times \cdot}$.

Comment: I think this link is relevant: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127/sp21/livebook/l_lineqs_solving.html

Comment: Well, $-1$ is in that field, but it is equal to $1.$

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of finite fields.  I suggest you remove all mention of finite fields and just say that the values of X,Y are in -1,0,1.  What about A?  Must it be in -1,0,1 or 0,1?  Is arithmetic done modulo 2, or is it done as an integer (without a mod 2 reduction)? Please [edit] the question to clarify.  Don't just leave clarifications and corrections in the comments.  Instead, revise your question so it contains all information, and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.